# Android wear error when using google play service

Tags: java, google-play-services, wear-os

I am using Android Studio 0.8.0 and created a project with Android Wear 4.4. I need to integrate it with Google Play Services. However, I got error as follows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find dynamic class com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl
```

I already added the play-services-wearable library in my build.gradle file. Also, I added following code in my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

but the error is still.

According to the guide in http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html, I also added the Proguard Exception in my /proguard-project.txt.

However, it does not work.

Could you give any idea to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Did you found working map on wearable device?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'`

in your dependencies.

So it would be (on the wear project):

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
}`

and in the mobile project:

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
    wearApp project(':wear')
}`

Comment: Thank you. Sure, I did what you said, the project could work in mobile phone, however it did not work in my Android wear device. I think there may be a problem in my wear device layout file. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I'm not sure if map API will work on wear. Try with something easier for start.